# How to solve login page, not redirecting

Tags: php, authentication, web

so I have a login page named index.php, the page does not seem to redirect to the home.php page.
I have tried to log in using all the correct user details but it stills stays on the index.php page and it also clears the data in the fields

I looked through my code and I cant seem to find the problem

```
             <?php
             require_once'Dbconfig.php';


             function login($umail, $upass)
             {
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
                     emailAddress=:umail AND userPass=:upass");
                 $stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail, ':upass'=>$upass));
                 $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FECTH_ASSOC);

                 if($stmt->rowCount() ==1)
                  {
                      $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($upass);

                      if($this->password_verify($upass, $hashed) == 1)
                       {
                             $_SESSION['user_session'] = 
                                $userRow['emailAddress'];
                                return true;
                       } 
                       else
                       {
                          return false;
                       }
                  }
               }

             if(isset($_POST['btn_login']))
             {
                 $umail             = $_POST['txt_umail'];
                 $upass         = $_POST['txt_upass'];

                  if($user->login($umail, $upass))
                  {
                      header('Location: home.php');
                      exit;
               }
               else
               {
                  $error[] = 'Wrong email or password!';
                }

           }


      ?>
```

Comment: why are you selecting the password if you are verifying it below.??

Comment: Should I then remove the section where I verify it @VishalParkash

Comment: check my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using else condition

```
<?php
require_once'Dbconfig.php';
function login($umail, $upass){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailAddress=:umail");
    $stmt->bindValue(":umail", $umail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userRow = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if($stmt->num_rows ==1){
        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($upass);
        if($this->password_verify($upass, $hashed)){
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['emailAddress'];
            return true;
            }else{
                return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh.. I lost 2 points.. :( those were hard earned points you downvoter..

Comment: I tried it out, but it still does not redirect @VishalParkash

Comment: it wasn't for you @Destiny :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129979/discussion-between-vishalparkash-and-destiny).

Comment: @Destiny Is your issue fixed?